# How to extract audio in 8khz using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, sox

I am using ffmpeg to extract the audio from a video. Below code downlaods the audio from a video file. I'm not sure how efficient this program is but I do know that it downloaods it in 48KHZ.

How do I use this program to extract audio from a video in 8Khz because the file is getting too big.

```
ffmpeg -i video_link -vn output.wav
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-ar` option to change frequency rate

```
ffmpeg -i video_link -vn -ar 8000 output.wav
```

If you want to try different formats of audio check the available formats in ffmpeg using `ffmpeg -formats` and available codecs using `ffmpeg -codecs`

Here's an example to extract to mp3 file

```
ffmpeg -i video_link -vn -ar 8000 -f mp3 output.mp3
```

Edit: as @llogan pointed out, `-f` option is not needed, ffmpeg automatically mux mp3 file.

```
ffmpeg -i video_link -vn -ar 8000 output.mp3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I have a question. In todays standards how do people save their data? Is 8Khz audio data good. Which format and size is good to use but takes as less resource as possible?

Comment: A lot of factors go into play when you reduce bitrate or sampling frequency of the audio file. When bitrate is lowered you can easily see a drop in audio quality. Using a higher bitrate is preferred(120kbps+) while sampling it in a lower frequency(in your case 8kHz). 
When you sample in frequency less than 20kHz, you may mess up bit depth and hear a lot of white noises in your audio. If you wish to sample it in lower frequency, you need higher bitrate to reproduce the same quality as that of 20kHz+.
Maybe some others can explain how they do it or what is the best way of doing it.

Comment: No need for `-f mp3`. It will know to use the MP3 muxer when outputting .mp3.